# Copy filenames, and add path prefix, in a directory, recursively

Tags: linux, shell-script, wildcards, rename, file-copy

I have a working directory: `/home/myusername/projectdir`
The working directory contains files and sub-directories. The depth of sub-directories is not known.
I want to put all the `*.log` files into the same output directory, with the base-names prefixed with the sub-directory path (substitutin `/` with `#`).

Example:

```
/home/myusername/projectdir/file1.log                  -> /home/myusername/output/file1.log
/home/myusername/projectdir/subdir/file2.log           -> /home/myusername/output/#subdir#file2.log
/home/myusername/projectdir/subdir/subsubdir/file3.log -> /home/myusername/output/#subdir#subsubdir#file3.log
```

I tried this:

```
cd "$PROJECT_DIR"
CDIR=""
for x in **/*.log; do
    if [ "$CDIR" != "$PROJECT_DIR/${x%/*}" ]; then

        CDIR="$PROJECT_DIR/${x%/*}"
        SUBDIR="${x%/*}"
        PREFIX=${SUBDIR//'/'/'#'}

        cd "$CDIR"
        for FILENAME in *.log; do
            NEWNAME="#$PREFIX#$FILENAME"
            cp "$FILENAME" "$OUTPUT_DIR/$NEWNAME"
        done
    fi
done
```

How can I do this more elegantly?

Comment: what do you mean by "more elegant"?

Comment: like, can I do this without the 2nd for loop, or with a more effective/simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `\0`-delimited strings, this can handle `spaces` and `\n` in file names.

```
cd "${PROJECT_DIR%/*}"
outdir="output"; mkdir -p "$outdir"
find "$PROJECT_DIR" -type f -name '*.log' -printf "%p\0${outdir}/%P\0" |
  awk 'BEGIN{FS="/";RS=ORS="\0"} 
       NR%2||NF==2 {print; next}
       {gsub("/","#"); sub("#","/#"); print}' |
    xargs -0 -n2 cp -T
```

- *`mkdir -p`* creates the destination directory (no error if it already exists).
- *`find`* prints `\0`-delimited file-paths (`%P` means without`find`'s `$1` directory-path).
- *`awk`* creates the 2 file-paths required by `cp`, as two `\0` delimited records.
- *`xargs`* reads `\0`-delimited file-paths, 2 at a time, and passes them to `cp -T`

Here is `tree` of the test *source* directory`

```
projectdir
├── file0.txt
├── file1.log
└── subdir
    ├── file2.log
    └── subsubdir
        └── file3.log

2 directories, 4 files
```

Here is `tree` of the *destination* directory`

```
output
├── file1.log
├── #subdir#file2.log
└── #subdir#subsubdir#file3.log

0 directories, 3 files
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

newdir=/absolute/path/output
olddir=/absolute/path/project

find $olddir -name '*log' | while read line ; do
  if [ "$olddir" == "$( basename "$line" )" ] ; then
    #just move the file if there are no subdirectories
    mv "$line" "$newdir"
  else
    #1) replace old project dir with nothing 
    #2) replace all slashes with hashes
    #3) set new outdir as prefix
    #4) hope that there are no colons in the filenames
    prefix="$( sed -e "s:$olddir::" -e 's:/:#:g'  -e "s:^:$newdir/:" <<<"$( dirname "$line")" )"
    mv "$line" "$prefix"#"$( basename "$line" )"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

`(cd "$PROJECT_DIR" && find . -name "*.log") | tar -cf - -T - | (cd $OUTPUT_DIR && tar -xf -)`

- cd to project directory
- find all of the log files
- tar's list of log files to stdout
- cd to output directory
- untar stdin

Comment: doesn't change the filenames